# REGEXP matching numbers always evaluates to true in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a trigger that should only allow an insert if REGEXP expression evaluated to true. However, the expression always seems to evaluate to true.

The even if I insert random characters, which are not allowed anywhere in the expression, a row is inserted.

The regex expressions works on online regex checkers. But will never fail when invoking mysql trigger.

BEGIN

```
-- find out what is the labelType based on the labelID
SET @labelType = ( SELECT labelTypeID 
                   FROM customer.label
                   WHERE labelID = NEW.labelID);

IF @labelType = 2 THEN -- 2 = date format in YYYY-MM-DD (ie: 2019-05-05)
    IF NEW.labelValue NOT REGEXP '[12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])' THEN
        SET @err_msg = CONCAT(NEW.labelValue, ' Invalid date format. Please make sure it conforms to YYYY-MM-DD.');

        SET @err_msg = left(@err_msg, 128);
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '41000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @err_msg;
    END IF;
```

Comment: If you are looking for invalid date strings, you might want to try `IF DATE(NEW.labelValue) IS NULL`. This will even invalidate a wrong date with the right format like `2019-07-32` or `2019-02-29`. Or `IF CONCAT(DATE(NEW.labelValue)) <> NEW.labelValue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `REGEXP` operator in versions of MySQL earlier than 8+ does not support `\d` as representing a single digit.  Instead, you should use `[0-9]`:

```
IF NEW.labelValue NOT REGEXP '[12][0-9]{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])'
THEN
    SET @err_msg = CONCAT(NEW.labelValue, ' Invalid date format. Please make sure it conforms to YYYYMMDD.');
```

Here is a demo showing that the above regex in fact works as expected in MySQL 5.7:

### Demo